# Integrable slowly varying function

Tags: integration, limits, laplace-transform, limsup-and-liminf, distribution-tails

We say a function $L$ is slowly varying if
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{L(tx)}{L(t)} = 1$$
for every $x > 0$.

Are there such $L$ that are integrable? Say $L$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$ and is
continuous with $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}L(t) = 0?$ I'm thinking of $L$ as the tail distribution of some non-negative random variable.

Comment: When I say integrable, I mean $\int_0^\infty L(s)ds < \infty.$

Answer (score 4):

No slowly varying function $L$ can be integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

It follows from the Potter bounds (e.g., see Theorem 1.5.6 of 
the book [Regular Variation](https://books.google.com/books?id=VCU5D4jMfiEC&q=Potter#v=snippet&q=Potter&f=false) by Bingham, Goldie, and Teugel), 
that for any $\delta>0$, one has
$$
L(x) \ge C_\delta x^{-\delta}
$$
for $x$ sufficiently large, where $C_\delta>0$.

This bound is also not difficult to prove directly from the uniform convergence theorem, which states that the limit $L(tx)/L(t)\to1$ is attained uniformly for $x$ in any compact subset of $(0,\infty)$: 
One shows that for all large enough $t$, 
$$ L(te^k) \ge L(t)e^{-\delta k}$$
by induction for $k=1,2,\ldots$, then writes $x$ in the form $te^k$ with $t$ in a fixed compact set $[T,Te^1]$. (Note $e^{-k}\ge x/(Te)$.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't think of an example with the extra requirements, but there certainly exists such $L$ that are integrable.

Take $L(x) =\log(x)^b$, where $b$ is a real number.

and let's show using L'Hopital that this function indeed is slowly varying.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(tx)^b}{\log(x)^b} = \frac{\frac{b\log(xt)^{b-1}}{x}}{\frac{b\log(x)^{b-1}}{x}} = \frac{\log(tx)^{b-1}}{log(x)^{b-1}}
$$
Repeated application will yield the desired result.

Now, $\log(x)^b$ is certainly integrable, although with a hideous expression resorting to special functions. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%28ln%28x%29%5Eb%29%20dx)

Comment: To add, trivialities such as $L(x) = 1$ certainly satisfy integrability.